# Error resulting from Tensorflow prediction fail

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, prediction

I have trained a TensorFlow CNN model to perform text classification.  The training completes and evaluates without issue, but when I send predictions to the model when it is hosted on GCP I am getting the following error that I am finding it hard to understand:

```
RuntimeError: Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="NodeDef mentions attr 'output_type' not in Op<name=ArgMax; signature=input:T, dimension:Tidx -> output:int64; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_UINT16, DT_INT16, DT_INT8, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_QINT8, DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_HALF]; attr=Tidx:type,default=DT_INT32,allowed=[DT_INT32, DT_INT64]>; NodeDef: predicted = ArgMax[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _output_shapes=[[-1]], output_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fc/logits, predicted/dimension)
     [[Node: predicted = ArgMax[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _output_shapes=[[-1]], output_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fc/logits, predicted/dimension)]]")
```

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is most likely a version mismatch between the tensorflow you used for training and exporting and the Cloud ML Engine runtime.

To fix this you have to deploy a `version` using the `gcloud` CLI (the web console doesn't support choosing the runtime-version) while specifying the runtime-version of your model.

Assuming you are locally on tensorflow 1.8 and trained and exported your model that way, you can as before use the console to upload your model into a bucket and create a model. Then in order to create a version, do as follows:

```
gcloud ml-engine versions create <version_name> \
--model=<model_name> \
--origin=<gs://bucket_name> \
--runtime-version=1.8
```

This solved the problem for me.